# React-markdown and react-syntax-highlighter

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown, react-syntax-highlighter

I'm building a blog with ReactMarkdown, and I want to render a custom component for the code blocks:

```
<ReactMarkdown
   children={content}
   rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
   components={{
     code({ node, inline, children, className, ...props }) {
          return <PrismHighlighter children={children}  {...props} />;
          }
    }}
/>
```

My 'PrismHighlighter' file consists in the following:

```
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { nightOwl } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/prism';

const SyntaxHighlight = ({ props, children }) => (
  <SyntaxHighlighter style={nightOwl} language="javascript" showLineNumbers {...props}>
    {children}
  </SyntaxHighlighter>
);

export default SyntaxHighlight;
```

The problem is the following: ReactMarkdown is receiving a string (what is okay), like this:

> ```
> nucleus_dataset =
> nucleus.create_dataset("PennFudan") DATASET_ID =
> nucleus_dataset.info()['dataset_id'] # Save unique ID for future use
>
> def format_img_data_for_upload(img_dir: str):   """Instantiates a
> Nucleus DatasetItem for all images in the PennFudan dataset.
>
>   Parameters   ----------   img_dir : str
>       The filepath to the image directory
>
>   Returns   -------   List[DatasetItem]
>       A list of DatasetItem that can be uploaded via the Nucleus API   """   img_list = []   for img_filename in os.listdir(img_dir):
>       img_id = img_filename.split('.')[0]
>       item = DatasetItem(
>           image_location=os.path.join(img_dir, img_filename), 
>           reference_id=img_id,
>       )
>       img_list.append(item)   return img_list
>
> img_list = format_img_data_for_upload(IMG_DIR)
>
> response = nucleus_dataset.append(img_list)
> ```

But ReactMarkdown sends to PrismHighlighter an array of objects, like this:
[example of what ReactMarkdown sends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swz8t.png)

This results of PrismHighlighter avoiding several lines and showing only half or less of the code, like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Y2y.png)

So, does anyone knows what happening here? I'm struggling with this for days now.

Comment: Hi, have you try to use the official exemple ? https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#use-custom-components-syntax-highlight

Comment: Hi @BENARDPatrick, yes! But the problem is that the content is coming from a CMS. And the codeblocks are written in html, so ReactMarkdown is receiving a string with html tags (eg: <code>my code here</code>), which works, but sending to ReactSyntaxHighlighter an array of objects...

Comment: Ok, so little question, why are you using a library that transform markdown to react component ? Maybe just using a standard markdown to HTML string should do the job no ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked

Comment: @BENARDPatrick but how do I render a react-syntax-highlighter component for the code blocks?

Comment: First you create a function that convert markdown to html, and once done, you give the result to SyntaxHighlighter as a uniq child. That's all.

Comment: @BENARDPatrickm\ yes, but the markdown file is large... it's not only code. So I would have to identify the content between different tags and render different components for those... that's why I chose ReactMarkdown at first

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar issue with latest version of `react-markdown`. I have written a detail blog on this problem [here](https://hannadrehman.com/blog/enhancing-your-react-markdown-experience-with-syntax-highlighting)

you can create a new `MarkdownRenderer` component which does this

```
import React from 'react';
import Markdown from 'react-markdown';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';
import rehypeRaw from 'rehype-raw';
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { dracula } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/prism';

type MarkdownRendererProps = {
  children: string;
};

export function MarkdownRenderer({ children: markdown }: MarkdownRendererProps) {
  return (
    <Markdown
      remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
      rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
      components={{
        code({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }: any) {
          const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || '');

          return !inline && match ? (
            <SyntaxHighlighter style={dracula} PreTag="div" language={match[1]} {...props}>
              {String(children).replace(/\n$/, '')}
            </SyntaxHighlighter>
          ) : (
            <code className={className} {...props}>
              {children}
            </code>
          );
        },
      }}
    >
      {markdown}
    </Markdown>
  );
}
```

Comment: No idea why it is not accepted as answer. I literally just copied you code to my solution and I have syntax highlighting implemented out of the box